# how to check if a value exists in a dictionary of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python

Suppose my dictionary of dictionaries called records is like this where first, second etc are keys

```
 records = {
                 first: {
                    "email": email,
                    "password": password,
                    "pwd_secret" : None
                     }

                 second: {
                    "email": email,
                    "password": password,
                    "pwd_secret" : code
                     }
           }
```

I then check if code is equal to the value of "`pwd_secret`" in any of the dicts. The code for that functionality works perfectly however my else statement does not work (if code is not the value of "`pwd_secret`" in any of the dicts, then i want to raise an error. However currently it just raises an error even if the code exists.) Any suggestions?

```
 for k, v in records.items():
                pwd_secret = v.get('pwd_secret')
                if pwd_secret == code:
                    hashed_password = hash_password(new_password)
                    v['password'] = hashed_password
                #else:
                    #raise ValueError("code is invalid")
```

Comment: What's the problem? You have an invalid secret and it raises an error you tell it to...

Comment: Please upgrade this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your posted code dies quickly due to undefined variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through the `values` and use an `if` condition:

```
for v in records.values():
    pwd_secret = v.get('pwd_secret')
    if pwd_secret == code:
        # found
```

You don't really need to go through `items` because it looks like you don't need the key.

As for your error, `ValueError` is raised from the `else` branch because the `pwd_secret` doesn't equal `code`. If your not expecting this then you should set a breakpoint inside your editor and step through your code line by line to see what's actually happening.

Another easier debugging step is to just `print` out what each of these values are:

```
for v in records.values():
    pwd_secret = v.get('pwd_secret')

    print(f"pwd secret: {pwd_secret} and code: {code}") # print values here

    if pwd_secret == code:
        print("Secret is valid!")
    else:
        raise ValueError("code is invalid")
```

Which might also point out that `v.get('pwd_secret')` is giving you the default value `None` if `'pwd_secret'` is not found in the inner dictionaries.

Additionally, if you want to check if *any* of the inner dictionaries have the code, you can use the built-in function [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(v.get('pwd_secret') == code for v in records.values()):
    print("Secret found!")
else:
    raise ValueError("Secret not found")
```

Comment: yea i guess it raises the error since my else statement raises the error before it can move onto checking if the other dicts have the code. im not sure how i could raise the error so that the error is raised after checking ALL the dicts. is there a pythonic shortcut way?

Comment: @shellysu you could use `any` to check if any of the dictionaries have the code. I've added an example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

assume this dictionary:

```
records = {
  'first': {
                "email": 1234,
                "password": 1234,
                "pwd_secret" : None
                 },
             'second': {
                "email": 1234,
                "password": 1234,
                "pwd_secret" : 'code'
                 }
       }
```

and testing loop:

```
for v in records.values():
  if v['pwd_secret'] == 'code':
    print('here...')
```

instead of the `print()` clause just put the necessary actions you wish to perform.
in other words - your code should work, the problem is probably not lying in finding the value in a nested dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Function:

```
def check_value(dict_of_dicts, value):
    return any(value in dict_.values() for dict_ in dict_of_dicts.values())
```

Example:

```
a = {
      'first': {
         "email": 'email',
         "password": 'password',
         "pwd_secret": None
      },

      'second': {
         "email": 'email',
         "password": 'password',
         "pwd_secret": 'code'
      }
}

check_value(a, 'code')
# True
```